# Delta Deployments OLTP/OLAP SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

I have a requirement to look at Delta deployments of OLTP Database and OLAP Cubes in SQL Server between UAT and Production and I wondered was this capable out-of-the-box with SQL Server?

I know SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) has a Schema comparison tool but that doesn't meet my requirements (other than schema), we are looking for the DB (Data) and also Cube..

Can a delta on a cube even be done?

Another option might be commercial tools (if they exist)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question after research carried out (not tested), I'm off the opinion that the tooling will be the best approach, evaluation steps next.

**OLTP Manual process**: DAC for OLTP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362011(v=vs.100).aspx

**OLAP manual process below**:
Use the Analysis Services Deployment Wizard to use the XMLA output files generated by an Analysis Services project to deploy the project's metadata to a destination server. Please see: [Using the Analysis Services Deployment Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176121%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Use the Synchronize Database Wizard to synchronize the metadata and data between any two Analysis Services databases. Please see: [Synchronizing Analysis Services Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

**Tooling** investigation Red-Gate :

SQL Comapre

SQL Data Compare

SSAS Compare

Hope this helps someone else!